# Не хватает практики JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я начал изучать **JavaScript.** И мне не хватает практики. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте какой нибудь сайт или книгу, которая есть упражнения. Желательно темы были по теме.

Comment: Лучшее упражнение - работа!

Comment: конечно закрыли как дубликат но с таким же успехом 70-80% всех вопросов можно закрыть так как они все дублируют друг друга

Comment: @MaximLensky, вопрос про книгу, закрыли дубликатом вопроса про книги, вроде все логично.

Comment: @Grundy тут на so много дубликатов ..если их все закрывать то и so можно закрыть так как все ответы уже есть здесь

Comment: @MaximLensky, к этому и надо стремиться. А не иметь 10 абсолютно одинаковых вопросов и ответов, копий друг друга

Comment: @Grundy согласен на 50%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую ежедневно хотя бы понемногу изучать ресурс **https://learn.javascript.ru/**. В конце каждой темы там есть задания и комментарии учащихся.

Если не боитесь английского то очень сильно советую **https://www.codewars.com/**. Это ресурс который предлагает вам именно решать небольшие задачки. Очень крутая штука.
Так же очень сильно советую **https://www.freecodecamp.org/**. Это тоже задачки, но тут как-то дружелюбнее. Попроще возможно чуть чуть. Как минимум обязательно загляните на фри код кэмп.

Ну и упомяну браузерную игрушку где вам нужно будет кодить на том же JS(язык можно выбрать), но на мой взгляд это наименее эффективный вариант из всех предложенных:
*https://codecombat.com/*.


Так же советую придумывать себе простые задачки и стараться их реализовать.

Недавно наткнулся на интересный репозиторий на гитхаб. Чувак как раз придумывает себе несложные задачи и реализовывает их на чистом js. К каждому проекту есть live demo. Советую посмотреть [этот репозиторий](https://github.com/bradtraversy/vanillawebprojects) и как минимум почитать код понравившегося мини проектика.

Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Вот несколько полезных ссылок, думаю, на первое время этого более чем предостаточно будет

1. https://learnjavascript.online/
2. https://learn.javascript.ru/
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/
4. https://htmldom.dev/
5. https://www.freecodecamp.org/ (если дружите с Английским)